# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c[_0x2374[1]]')

Tags: javascript

First of all, I am not an expert at coding Javascript. I have only begun about a month ago, starting from Codecademy. I have a Javascript code here that gives me an error that I am unable to solve:

```js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c[_0x2374[1]]')
```

My main goal for this script is that when this script is to be put into the Javascript console on the website [Ourworldoftext.com](http://www.Ourworldoftext.com), I want the script to first of all ask for a url link from the user, and then when the key "ctrl A" is pressed, it inputs a hyperlink that links to the inputted url (var e) onto the website where the yellow cursor is.  I have done extensive research and found no specific answer on how to correct this problem.  Of course, the solution could be blatantly staring me in the face (again, I am a complete beginner at Javascript).  However, I cannot seem to fix this, which is why I am posting this so that I can get some answers on how to get rid of this error.

Please note that this code was specifically designed to be implemented into the website [www.ourworldoftext.com](http://www.ourworldoftext.com). It was originally supposed to be for the site www.yourworldoftext.com, but I have tried converting the variables in this code to make sense in www.ourworldoftext.com. Here is the code:

```js
var _0x2374 = ["_state.selected", "parentNode", 
               "tileX", "data", "tileY", "onkeydown", 
               "keyCode", "http://www.ourworldoftext.com/ajax/urllink/", 
               "path", "worldName", "rowIndex", "cellIndex", 
               "post", "right", "moveCursor", "onkeyup", 
               "Link URL"];

setInterval(function() {
    c = $(_0x2374[0])[0];
    f = c[_0x2374[1]][_0x2374[1]][_0x2374[1]][_0x2374[1]];
    x = $[_0x2374[3]](f, _0x2374[2]);
    y = $[_0x2374[3]](f, _0x2374[4]);
});

var e = prompt(_0x2374[16]);
document[_0x2374[5]] = function(_0xf18fx1) {
    var _0xf18fx2 = _0xf18fx1[_0x2374[6]];
    keys[_0xf18fx2] = true;
    if (keys[17] && keys[65]) {
        jQuery[_0x2374[12]](_0x2374[7], {
            namespace: _state.worldName,
            tileY: YX_yx[0],
            tileX: YX_yx[1],
            charY: YX_yx[2],
            charX: YX_yx[3],
            url: url
        });
        w[_0x2374[14]](_0x2374[13]);
    };
};

document[_0x2374[15]] = function(_0xf18fx1) {
    if (keys[17] && keys[88]) {
        changelink();
    };
    var _0xf18fx2 = _0xf18fx1[_0x2374[6]];
    keys[_0xf18fx2] = false;
};
changelink = function() {
    e = prompt(_0x2374[16]);
};
```

Please go easy on me, as I am a beginner at coding Javascript.
Thank you so much.

Comment: your code is very unreadable for someone who's new to javascript

Comment: why are your keywords in an array rather then written normally?

Comment: It would help a lot if you wouldn't post and work with uglified code. Please show us the original code.

Comment: `"_state.selected"` does not appear to be a valid DOM selector. Also, your `setInterval` misses an interval, and might run before the DOM is loaded.